# Create Controls in Gambas with dynamic Eventname

Tags: controls, gambas

In Gambas I can create Controls like this:

```
btn = New Button(parent) As "MyButton"
```

Now events listen on:

```
MyButton_Click()
```

But how can I create Elements with dynamic name, like:

```
dim tmp as string
tmp = "MyButton"
btn = New Button(parent) As tmp
```

The last line does not work, but thats the question how to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to attach the Object to its Parentform with this:

```
dim tmp as string
tmp = "MyButton"

btn = New Button(parent)
Object.Attach(btn, ParentForm, tmp)
```